# Logistic differential equation to model population

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem Description:

The population of the world was about  5.3 billion in 1990. Birth rate in the 1990s ranged from 35 to 40 million per year and death rates ranged from 15 to 20 million per year. Let's assume that the carrying capacity for world population is 100 billion.

Write the logistic differential equation for these data. (Because the initial population is small compared to the carrying capacity, you can take k to be an estimate of the initial relative growth rate.)

My calculation:

Because it's a logistic model and the carrying capacity is 100 billion, I wrote the differential equation as:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = ky(1-\frac{y}{100})$
100 denotes 100 billions for the carrying capacity.

My question:

How can we know the value of k?

Answer (score 0):

You have the hint: "you can take $k$ to be an estimate of the initial relative growth rate".

Since, $\text{growth rate} = \text{birth rate} - \text{death rate}$, we get that the growth rate is ranged from $15$ to $35$ million per year. Hence, the average growth rate is $\frac{15+35}{2} = 25$ million per year. Therefore, the  initial *relative* growth rate  $k = \frac{25}{5 300} = 0,0047169$.

I think it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Description:

The population of the world was about 5.3 billion in 1990. Birth rate in the 1990s ranged from 35 to 40 million per year, and death rates ranged from 15 to 20 million per year. Let's assume that the carrying capacity for world population is 100 billion.

Logistic Differential Equation:

The logistic differential equation for this scenario is given by:

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = ky\left(1 - \frac{y}{100 \text{ billion}}\right) $

Here, $ y $ represents the population, $ k $ is the growth rate constant, and $ 100 \text{ billion} $ is the carrying capacity.

Determining the Value of $ k $:

To determine the value of $ k $, we use the initial condition that the population in 1990 was about 5.3 billion. Let $ y(1990) = 5.3 \text{ billion} $. Substituting this into the differential equation:

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = k \times 5.3 \times 10^9 \left(1 - \frac{5.3 \times 10^9}{100 \times 10^9}\right) $

To fully determine $ k $, additional information is needed, such as population growth or death rates.